# Why is there no error when defining a function using these overloaded operators?

Tags: sml

I am reading *Programming with Standard ML* by Colin Myers, Chris Clack, and Ellen Poon. In § 2.4.1 *Restricted polymorphic functions*:

> Unlike the operators `=` and `<>`, the other comparison operators (`>`, `<` etc.) are *overloaded*; they are not restricted polymorphic and therefore the following definition fails:
>
> ```
> - fun wrong_ordered (x, y, z)
>      = (x < y) andalso (y < z);
> Error: overloaded variable "<" cannot be resolved
> ```
>
> This failure occurs because SML does not know the types of `x`, `y` and `z`.

When I entered that definition into SML/NJ 110.99.2 and Poly/ML 5.9, I did not get any error message. The definition succeeds:

```
- fun wrong_ordered (x, y, z) = (x < y) andalso (y < z);
val wrong_ordered = fn : int * int * int -> bool
```

Why did I not get the error that the authors said I would be getting?

Comment: That book is four years older than SML '97 and is based on the earlier version from 1990.

Comment: @molbdnilo What did SML '97 change to allow the function definition above to be valid?

Comment: See the answer from Andreas Rossberg, who is possibly the most SML-knowledgeable person you will find on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book predates SML'97. With that language version, type resolution for overloaded operators was refined. In particular, overloaded types now default to `int` when they cannot be resolved by context.

Comment: "type resolution for overloaded operators was refined" — What does that mean? How does "refining" cause the error in versions of SML before SML '97?

Comment: @Flux, in SML'90, when the program context provides no information to resolve an overloaded type, it was simply an error; whereas SML'97 improved the rules by introducing the concept of a default type, which it falls back to in that case. SML'97 also made more precise how large the program context is that is considered before defaulting kicks in (at most the smallest enclosing module-level declaration, though that is still rather fuzzy).

Answer (score 1):

Barring any types specified, your compiler determines that `wrong_ordered` takes three `int` values.

Compare this to OCaml, which does have polymorphic compare.

```
# let wrong_ordered x y z = x < y && y < z;;
val wrong_ordered : 'a -> 'a -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
```

If you specify even one parameter's type for `wrong_ordered` the other types will be likewise inferred.

```
fun wrong_ordered (x: real, y, z) = (x < y) andalso (y < z);
```

Type:

```
val wrong_ordered = fn: real * real * real → bool;
```

*Keep in mind that the book you're referencing was published *29* years ago.*